# Lennox furnace 3 flashing lights

Tags: furnace

Have a new construction house, and lived here about 2.5 yrs. Turned on my furnace last night worked fine. This morning, it kept turning on then kicking off with no burners coming on.

I noticed the red light was flashing 3 times. Looked up some info and pulled the hose off and noticed the part it plugs into on the fan was all corroded.

What causes this? Is this from the A/C? Everything was fine last year. I do have a whole house humidifier, but no problems last season.

[image]

Comment: Btw, i cleaned it out with a small nail.. and the burners lit up, and is now working correctly. But I still wonder where that gunk in there is coming from. Looks like deposits built up from evaporated water.

Comment: Please take the [tour], then provide and accept a proper answer below so this post can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to answer per request.

Assumed to be somehow related to me having hard water and a whole house humidifier attached to my furnace. I have to go in at least once a season to be proactive and clear the debris clogging the hole, or the system will throw an error and not start the burners (for good reason) as it thinks the exhaust fan is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I found a website to check the pressure switch (sucking it and hearing a click), and hose and not about the small hole on the furnace itself. I cleaned with a small nail.

3 blinking red light on the bottom and will start and then stop after 3 seconds.

My exhaust air is on the room so I couldn't check there.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. Answers should be self-contained and not refer to comments (which are to be considered temporary). You may want to revise a bit with that in mind. In particular, the phrase "and hose and not about the small hole" is unclear to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cool, glad this helped you out in some way. I haven't figured it out myself why it happens, but I have to clean out at least once a year. I have a whole house humidifier (with hard water) and assume it's some how related to that.  Do you have a humidifier attached to your hvac?

Comment: @eagei22 no I do not. I've scheduled a maintenance service with my local HVAC to ask and see if they can clean it out the "right" way. Too bad they are booked until March! I was able to remove more of the residue with an unfolded paperclip but don't think it's the best way to clean or prevent this from happening.